# CascadeType.ALL does not work with FetchType.EAGER

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have an entity like this:

```
@Entity
public class Directory extends Node
{
   @OneToMany(cascade= CascadeType.ALL,fetch= FetchType.EAGER)
   private List<Node> nodes = new ArrayList<Node>();
}
```

The mapping is unidirectional.

When I use FethType.EAGER, the cascade option has no effect. This code saves the both entities fine when there is no eager option. What is the problem here?

```
public void addDirectory(String name, long directoryId, User owner)
{
    Directory parent = entityManager.find(Directory.class, directoryId);
    Directory dir = new Directory(name,owner);
    parent.add(dir);
    owner.incrementRevision();
    entityManager.merge(owner);
}
```

parent.add() just adds the entity to a collection.

```
public boolean add(Node e)
{
    return nodes.add(e);
}
```

Comment: What's the CascadeType on the User class?  I don't see where you're persisting the Directory.

Comment: The directory is getting added to the parent, which has cascade all set. The parent is attached to the entity manager at that point because its loaded in the first line.

Comment: Sure.  The parent is attached to the entity manager but unless an explicit merge or persist is called on the parent then there is nothing to cascade down to the children.

The implicit flush that happens when the transaction is closed won't automatically make the children persistent.   You have to call merge/persist on the child either directly or indirectly (by calling it on the parent) in order for the child entity to be made persistent.

Comment: Then why does this exact code works when eager fetching is not set?

Comment: Post the code for `parent.add()` please.

Comment: Edited the original quesiton.

Comment: I'm not sure why a lazy vs. eager cascade would have any effect.  Have you tried doing an entityManager.persist(dir) after you new it up?

Comment: You say the mapping is unidirectional from Directory to List<Node>.  But when you have a `@OneToMany` relationship, you have to use `@JoinTable` to create a unidirectional correct mapping.

My second remark:  When you add a Node to a directory, it's it a more logical solution to merge your directory. And have the User be cascaded (because he is supplementary information).
If you don't want that, you should also show the User class. Maybe the fault lies there.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use getNodes().add instead of just nodes.add, some providers might have trouble with this if they are using weaving to process your entities.